# How can I call all items in a list item?

Tags: python, django

So in django, lets say you create a list through .append like so:

```
  group = []
  people = humans.objects.all()
  for X in people:
      X.update(name = Bob)
      group.append(X.idnum)
```

If you wanted to get some of the items in the group list without it displaying like this " u'23' ", 
you would have to call group[0] or any othe number to find the one youre looking for. My question is how can I get all of them at once without the u''. So if i have three peope in the group, I want their idnums to come out as 232528 instead of " u'23' u'25' u'28' " without me haveing to do group[0][1][2] since I want always know how many are in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the str.join method. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

```
"".join(group)
```

or if you want a number instead of a string

```
int("".join(group))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a iteration and then add the string together:

```
list = [...]
result = ''
for item in list:
    result += str(item)
```

The result would be '232528' if the items in the list are  u'23' u'25' u'28'